# Calculate agreement for a specific row in a table in R

Tags: r, plot, statistics, correlation

1. Hello! I am new to R and I have this table that I want to find the correlation, how much agreement is here in the 3rd row between all three tosses. How can I calculate this for more than two values for a specific row? (heads is 1, tails is 2) Can I check for agreement between one column vs all the rest?

   ```
        library(readxl)
        > COIN_TOSS <- read_excel("C:/Users/user/Desktop/COIN TOSS.xlsx")

             TOSS #1 TOSS #2 TOSS #3

    1         2         2         2
    2         2         2         1
    3         1         1         2
    4         2         1         1
    5         2         1         1
    6         2         1         2
    7         1         1         2
    8         1         1         2
    9         1         1         1
   10         2         1         1
   ```
2. Also, I want to print a plot, with the sum of values. I have the top 3 values of each column (10 columns in sum) with this: (Am most frequent values are these)

   ```
   am <- excel__data$AM
   oneam <- sort(table(am),decreasing=TRUE)[1:3]
   >am
   3  2  4   
   31 26 24
   ```

For the plot I used this, but the y-axis stays the same with the max value being 30, and not all values (stacked up) are visible. How can I change it to go up to 200? Can I use something else besides plot and points?

```
 plot(oneam, pch=10, col='red')
 points(onecm, pch=10,col='blue') 
 points(onefm, pch=10,col='green')
 points(onekk, pch=10,col='yellow') 
 points(onekm, pch=10,col='black')
 points(onels, pch=10,col='orange')
```

Answer (score 0):

"Agreement" and "Correlation" are very different things.

If you want to simply look at "agreement" you could calculate a row-wise mean and standard deviation. Low standard deviations would indicate that all tosses have been fairly close, if you want to you could even standardize by dividing SD/MEAN to get the Coefficient of Variance a % metric.

You can even be more specific and calculate a "distance measure" from one specific toss to the other two e.g.:

```r
library(dplyr)
COIN_TOSS %>%
 mutate(Toss3_Delta = ((TOSS1+TOSS2)/2-TOSS3)/((TOSS1+TOSS2)/2))
```

Now if we are talking about correlation in your example this works only column wise because three cases are not enough to calculate a correlation.

This works:

```r
library(magrittr)

COIN_TOSS %$%
  cor()
```

Comment: I edited the post and specified that I am looking for the agreement. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: @NewbieEevee In this case really look into metrics of variance. Most likely standard deviation already satisfies most criteria but CoV can also be relevant. If you want to look at individual columns simply calculate how many SD there are from the mean.